# awk to filter lines in a file based on match and conditional of another file

Tags: awk

I have a file with this format:

**file1**

```
id1   12.4
id2   21.6
id4   17.3
id6   95.5
id7   328.6
```

And I want to filter it based on another file with the format:

**file2**

```
id1   11.5
id2   10.4
id3   58.4
id4   24.6
id5   234.4
id6   2.5
id7   330.6
```

First, I would like to match ids between files. Then, I want to keep the lines in file1 in which the score (second column) is greater than the score in file2. It would output this:

```
id1   12.4
id2   21.6
id6   95.5
```

I started writing the code like `awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1][$2][$0]; next } $1 in a {}' file1 file2` which I think would match the ids between files, but I don't know how to complete the code to filter by the scores.

Answer (score 2):

You could write the awk command first reading *file2*, and then keep track of the values by setting the value `a[$1] = 0+$2` and add zero for a numeric comparison

Then you can do the comparison with *file1*

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1] = $2+0; next } $1 in a && $2+0 > a[$1]' file2 file1
```

Output

```
id1   12.4
id2   21.6
id6   95.5
```

Comment: Thanks, that really works! Although now I have two similar sets of files, where in file1 the id and score columns are the 4th and 6th, and in file2 they are 1st (id) and 3rd (score). I tried running `awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1] = $3+0; next } $4 in a && $6+0 > a[$1]' file2 file1` but I get no output. It seems that a[$1] is blank. Could you explain further how your line works and why mine does not? Thanks!

Comment: It should be like this `awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1] = $3+0; next } $4 in a && $6+0 > a[$4]' file2 file1` where the last comparision is `> a[$4]` If I run this code with the columns that you specified, I get the expected outcome.